# Handling the NameError when using 'threading' and 'schedule' in Python

Tags: multithreading, jupyter-notebook, schedule

I use 'threading' and 'schedule' simultaneously in Python.
for example :

```
> import threading, schedule
>
> def func(module_name):
>     exec(open(module_name).read())
>
> def run_thread(module_name):
>     thread = threading.Thread(target= func,
>                               args = (module_name,))
>     thread.start()
>
> schedule.every().day.at("09:15:00").do(run_thread, 'external_code.py')
> # "import pandas as pd" is declared in 'external_code.py'
> while True :
>    time.sleep(1)
>    schedule.run_pending()
```

Then, I face the NameError as below.

```
Exception in thread Thread-7:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-2-14c923896530>", line 12, in func
    exec(open(path).read())
  File "<string>", line 1066, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 546, in __init__
NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
```

So, I guess, Pandas module declared as "pd" in "external_code.py' cannot be read by the thread.
How could I fix this??

Thank you.

Without using threading, I don't face this error.
But when using threading, the error above is encountered.